# Classical Cryptography Tools

Tags: cryptography, tools, cryptanalysis

I'm wondering if there are any tools out there that can assist in solving classical cipher text.  I'm looking into developing some tools such as frequency analysis, transposition tools and so on but want to know what is already out there.  I suppose it wouldn't be just a technique specific tool such as for caeser ciphers only but something that might help in solving something that may or may not be a caeser sipher.  I know it sounds a bit shady but its all for educational purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect most cryptographers would probably roll their own quick script to do these computations, using Python or your favorite other rapid prototyping language.  The book *Cryptanalysis* by Helen Gaines is a highly regarded introduction to cryptanalysis of classical ciphers.

I don't know of a general suite of software for cryptanalysis of classical ciphers (though that doesn't mean it doesn't exist).

That said, Google turned up this: [Ganzúa](http://ganzua.sourceforge.net/en/index.html).  I have no prior experience of knowledge of it, so I don't know whether it's any good.

Answer (score 11):

http://www.cryptool.org/ - free, and have all that you need for educational purposes. I use it in different cryptography trainings.
From their site:

" Numerous classic and modern cryptographic algorithms (encryption and decryption, key generation, secure passwords, authentication, secure protocols, etc.)
 Visualization of several algorithms (Caesar, Enigma, RSA, Diffie-Hellman, digital signatures, AES, etc.)
 Cryptanalysis of several algorithms (Vigenère, RSA, AES, etc.)
 Cryptanalytical measurement methods (entropy, n-grams, autocorrelation, etc.)
 Related auxiliary methods (primality tests, factorization, base64 encoding, etc.)
 Number theory tutorial
 Comprehensive online help
 Accompanying script with additional information about cryptology"